# Can I lower vending machine prices?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I want to maximize the bang for my buck. *BioShock 2* had the "[Vending Expert](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_2_Gene_Tonics#Vending_Expert)" gene tonic, which lowered vending machine prices. Does *BioShock Infinite* have anything similar?

Comment: I assume you tried the 'make-machines-friendly' vigor already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a single Discount Dollar Bill machine in the courtyard of the Hall of Heroes that sells a pistol clip upgrade for half the price (side note: buying this upgrade does not affect the Scavenger Hunt achievement). Other than that, you are out of luck.

Using Possession on a vending machine causes it to drop a small amount of money but the prices remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Similar, yes, but not the same. The Possession vigor will cause any vending machine to hork up a pile of Silver Eagles, once per machine. So you get some coin out of the machines, but there is no way to affect the prices directly.